# Problem with Hyperlink in Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

   <ItemTemplate>
      <li class="closed" >
           <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="toggler off" 
                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NEXT.GIF" 
                Text="<%#Container.DataItem%>" ID="HyperLink1">
           </asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
   </ItemTemplate>

 </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to get the text in the hyperlink from the arraylist

in my ascx code

I am trying to do this bt its showing error

```
 HyperLink hypl = (HyperLink)Repeater1.FindControl("HyperLink1");
 hypl.Text = ar.ToString();
 hypl.NavigateUrl = "http//www.yahoo.com";
```

Anyone is having idea how to resolve this problem

Comment: First of all what exception do you get ? And do you have an option to change your datasource from arraylist to list&lt;T>

Comment: Actually its not showing any output.No I can't change from Arraylist to list.Earlier I was using <a href> in the ascx and was using Repeater1.Datasource=ar; Repeater1.Databind(); so it was working fine....but now I wanna use <Asp:Hyperlink> but its not showing output..I doubt if If I m making mistake in writing 
Text=<%#Container.DataItem%> ...

Comment: But if I m using the same ( Repeater1.Datasource=ar; Repeater1.Databind()) with asp:Hyperlink i am getting this error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl'

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware, but if you set both the ImageUrl and Text properties on the hyperlink, the ImageUrl property takes precedence and the Text is not used/displayed. You seem to be using both...

Comment: I have removed the ImageUrl and I m presently using this...

 ar = RemoveDups(ar);//removing duplicates
          
        //   Repeater1.DataSource = ar;
          //  Repeater1.DataBind();

            HyperLink hypl = (HyperLink)Repeater1.FindControl("HyperLink1");
            hypl.Text = ar.ToString();
            hypl.NavigateUrl = "http://www.meri.com";
            foreach (RepeaterItem rptrItem in Repeater1.Items)
            {
                 ArrayList ar1 = new ArrayList();
                  .... 
                      .....

Comment: but the problem is if I m not binding my repeater1 before it is showing object reference not found and if I uncomment repeater1.datasource it is showing problem I stated above literalControl one ..don't know how to approach it...the thing is I m using RepeaterItem also later......so need to bind repeater1 with something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a repeater control, you can't use FindControl to locate the hyperlink by name because there can be more than one (this is a template, and it gets rendered 0 to n times).

You need to do the assignment of values to the hyperlink multiple times, once for each item that is bound. This is a job for the repeater's ItemDataBound event. Try something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li class="closed" >
       <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="toggler off" 
            ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NEXT.GIF" 
            Text="<%#Container.DataItem%>" ID="HyperLink1">
       </asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then you need to handle the event like so:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink hypl = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
    hypl.Text = ar.ToString();
    hypl.NavigateUrl = "http//www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the reply actually in my case I am getting most of the values from strings or arraylist not directly from column in datasource so I want to do all my thing in one function because otherwise other array or string will be out of scope.
Current i m doing in page_load()
and in that I m using foeach(repateritem item in repeater1.items){}

Comment: Just store the array in a private field or property on your page's class. That way it will stay in scope while the binder events fire.
You aren't likely to find a way to do that all during page load using the built-in repeater's mechanisms easily. You could wait until after the whole repeater binds, then walk the repeater's control tree all at once, but that's a LOT of unnecessary work for this case.